# This code sometimes work or sometimes through an error message during runtime

Tags: excel, vba

The code mentioned below sometimes work and sometimes throw an error message

Can someone tell me why this is happening or any alternative to this

```
Sheet1.Range("H2", Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Clear
```

Error message is

```
"Run-time error '1004':Application defined or object-defined error"
```

Comment: you should be more specific when referencing to the Worksheet. Replace "Sheet1" with a declared object and also put this in front of "Range("O"...)". Something like: ws.range

Comment: Error occurs when Sheet1 is not active at runtime, because `Range("O"...` is implicitly belonging to the Active worksheet, and since a range cannot span multiple worksheets, the error is expected. The solution is to fully qualify your ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Now it should work:

```
With Sheet1

.Range("H2", .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Clear

End With
```

Only the First Range was Getting the Sheet reference, Second Range and Row functions were not.

Comment: There can be a better way of doing what you are trying, if you can explain what exactly you want to achieve, maybe I can suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Create a with statement referring BOTH workbook & worksheet to avoid errors if you have another workbook open
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Calculate LastRow and check if it is correct
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
        'Clearly show your range to be clear
        .Range("H2:O" & LastRow).Clear
    End With

End Sub
```